# How to do Declaration Merging in TypeScript 2 without installing an NPM package?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

There's a lot of old information floating around from previous versions of TypeScript which use different tooling.

If you want to add typings for a particular NPM package, your first step is to try `npm install @types/<package name>`. Most packages will either ship with their own typings (located in `/node_modules/<package name>/index.d.ts`) or else will have an accompanying package `@types/<package name>`.

Occasionally, though, we want to alter types with our own extensions.

1. **How do we extend a type in an NPM module, which does not have a `@types` package?**

We don't want to write and publish our own NPM package. Can we simply put a `.d.ts` file in our project? What should we call this file? Where does it go? How do we tell TypeScript to visit it?

2. **How do we extend intrinsic types from whatever environment our app runs on?**

If our app lives in node, `@types/node` brings in all the types we would expect. But what if we want to perform declaration merging on a node type? How do we do this?

If our app lives on the web, we can expect intrinsic variables like `window`. The `--lib` compiler option (or `"lib": ["dom"]` in tsconfig) will bring in these types. How do we perform declaration merging on window and other intrinsic DOM types?

Comment: have you tried extending existing types?

Comment: @MedetTleukabiluly I assume you mean declaring new interfaces which inherit the target types. I could do that, but that's not the "right" answer here.